# 240v at the breaker not the other end

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, 240v, well-pump

I have a well pump on what I  pretty sure is a dedicated 240v/60a circuit.

I have had to run a new line for part of this circuit and replace a segment. I connected the new segment at the same point where the old line connected. I installed a new breaker too.

Everything measures as expected at the breaker box. 240v across the breakers and 120v from each breaker to the ground/neutral bar.

Back down at the junction though I don't have any voltage. Nothing between the two hot wires where I'd expect 240v and just measured 240v on the breaker. Nothing between ground and either of the hots, where I just measured 120v at the breaker.

Also at this junction there is another single black wire besides the black and white pair from the breaker. I measure 120v between this mystery wire and the other wires from the breaker. I also get 120v from this wire and the ground of the black/white pair.

I am out of ideas how there is not 240v at the junction and I cannot figure where/why this single black conductor comes from.

I did check all the other breakers on the panel and observed all of the wires including the mysterious single conductor at the junnction lose energy when the well breaker is off. And no other breakers have any affect.

Really hoping someone here has some idea what's going on?

Comment: You evidently have something (pump starter or pressure switch) between the breaker and the junction box. "Mysterious new wires" don't self-generate, they come from other devices or junction boxes, and you need to find that. At which point, if you share details, this might become answerable... 60A is a BIG pump.

Comment: @Ecnerwal any tips on how to identify this wire? It's coming fromt the breaker side and goes to hot on the pressure switch at the pump. The wires between the breaker and this junction are buried in the walls and not physically traceable. I thought at first it would be coming from one of the other breakers. I went thru all of them watching voltage and the only one that had any affect was the well pump breaker. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: There's either a junction box along the way you need to find, or else you need to run entirely new cable/wires from the breaker to this point, since obviously the black and white at the junction box are NOT connected to the black & white at the breaker, though the "mysterious extra wire" is, in some manner, connected to it. So, go looking for junction box access covers along the way.

Comment: Are you sure both ends of the cable *are the same cable*?  How did you do the splices? When doing splices did you remove the insulation from the part of the wire which contacts the splice device's metal bits? (they don't auto-pierce like an automotive connector)

Comment: @Harper yes the insulation is peeled just far enought to make good connections at the breaker and the splice. I am making an assumption about both ends of the cable when I turn off the breaker and climb under the house the splice shows every wore has zero power. And when the breaker is on I get 120v on W/B/G of the cable against this mystery black single conductor. I'm searching for a point in between where there's a junction of some kind. No helpful results yet. I'm guessing W and G are tied together somewhere. But how was working on this side of the splice before I changed the other side?

Comment: In a working system, W (neutral) and G (safety ground) will be tied together at the *neutral-ground equipotential bond*.  Note that to do its job, the N-G bond could as easily be a 1-volt transformer (intentional 1VAC bias), or even a car battery (12VDC 0VAC bias)... but we use a 0V/0V bias because it's cheaper.

Comment: @Harper this panel is connected directly to the master switch for the property and the N-G is on the same buss bar. In this case of trying to get 240v the N is instead in one of the breaker terminals. At this point I can measure 120v to the N-G bar for both legs and 240v across the legs. If there's a junction in the circuit, is it possible to reintroduce a Neutral and only have a 120v circuit? This is what I'm seeing, just cannot physically find where it is happening behind the walls.

Comment: What the white wire is, is decided by where it's punched down on the supply end.  If not neutral, it is suppposed to be re-marked with colored tape or paint.  The N-G bond is supposed to be at the first switch past the meter, but pre-2008 they often ran the first cable 3-wire H-H-N, and established ground at the first real breaker panel (but black-white-green cable would not be legal for that use).  Anyway, it may be time to unhook all wires and do some wire tracing. Own any resistors of known value?

Comment: This house is pre-2008 and has had several owner mods down thru the years. I do not have any resistors. I agree about unhooking and tracing though. Any tips or gotchas to be aware of?